# Spring Data - how to select the entity by polymorphic relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, polymorphism, spring-data

Have successfully built the common polymorphic model, just like this:

```
public interface IProduct {}
```

... there two interface implementations are available.

# 1

```
@Entity
public class Cup impements IProduct, Serializable {
    ... setter&getter&equals&hashCode
}
```

# 2

```
@Entity
public class Kettle implements IProduct, Serializable {
     ... setter&getter&equals&hashCode
}
```

These two products are used as a polymorphic dependencies to the `Item` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Item implements Serializable {

...

@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "type"))
@AnyMetaDef(
       idType = "long",
       metaType = "string",
       metaValues = {
              @MetaValue(targetEntity = Cup.class, value = "cup"),
              @MetaValue(targetEntity = Kettle.class, value = "kettle")
       })
@JoinColumn(name = "product")
private IProduct product;
    ...
}
```

Have found the configuration works fine according to the generated data though.

However, I'm unable to build the lookup query to find the `Item` by a product using the Spring Data repository:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {
    Item findByProduct(IProduct product);
}
```

... the app won't launch due to `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [product] on this ManagedType` error.

Have tried to include to the interface the `getId()` getter and to use the abstract class with the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation.

Still doesn't work. Is there a way to find an entity by it's polymorphic dependency?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I'm having exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Jules, yeah. It's necessary to accompany the method with `@Query` annotation. It's like the `@Query("select i from Item i where i.product = :product")` annotation will let the above code work. In order to use the named parameter `:product` you've to redesign the arguments of the method to `@Param("product") IProduct product` as well

Comment: best answer your own question then and accept it